# Finding recorded sub-signal in the original audio signal

Tags: python, cross-correlation, waveform-similarity

I have the original record of a song, and some fragment of the same song recorded by a microphone. I need to find the time where the fragment is appearing in the original. 
I have tried to use cross-correlation, the results are good but sometimes it gives a completely different part of the song that is similar (same notes but not the same words).
How can I solve this problem ? Could the cross-correlation value be higher than the time when the sub-signal is found ? 
Different approaches are welcome also. 
Here is my code for the correlation implementation.

```
#compute correlation
correlation = correlate(reference,signal,mode='valid',method='direct')
#get maximum index
index = np.argmax(corr)
#extract from the reference 
extract = reference[index:index + len(sec)]
```

You can see the highest peak in the beginning, but I know it should be later. How can I find the real signal in this case ?
[image: Cross-Correlation plot]

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by "not bad but could be better"? Could you show an example where it fails and explain why it fails? Then maybe we can suggest a solution for this particular problem.

Comment: I mean it gives me a close index, but it is like one or 0.5 seconds off. I need it to be as accurate as possible

Comment: Well, if done correctly it shouldn't. Maybe your question should be "why is my correlation-based estimator off"? You may have to show a concrete example to understand your problem.

Comment: I see your point. My problem is a bit different now. I edited the question

Comment: Thanks Florian for commenting :)

Comment: Could you give more information on the signal from the microphone? Is there additional background noise or just "normal" microphone noise? Is the microphone fixed in relation to the sound source (ie no changes in intensity due to distance variations)? Is the audio played back in stereo and are the channels playing the same audio, or is it different? There can be many reasons for this. Have you tried some spectral filtering? Is there a specific signal in your sample that is dominating the audio? Have you tried audio fingerprinting, such as Chromaprint?